# Smarty - href link not displaying

Tags: smarty, whmcs

I have the following code block in a Smarty .tpl file used in my WHMCS template.

```
{foreach from=$departments key=num item=department}
  <a class="list-group-item" href="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?step=2&amp;deptid={$department.id}">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    <strong>{$department.name}</strong>
    {if $department.description}
      <p>{$department.description}</p>
    {/if}
  </a>
{foreachelse}
  <span class="list-group-item">{include file="$template/includes/alert.tpl" type="info" msg=$LANG.nosupportdepartments textcenter=true}</span>
{/foreach}
```

If I try to add a new href below the closing {foreachelse} it doesn't display the new link on the page, but if I put it before the opening {foreach then it displays correctly.

I've never worked with Smarty before. Is this a common issue, and if so, is there a solution to it?

Comment: Can you please put your full `{foreach}` block, until the `{/foreach}` closing tag?

Comment: check if you have any values in `{$departments|var_dump}`

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP additional code added to the question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP I'm dumb. I should have added the new href after the closing {/foreach}. Note to self, don't work on your website at 3am. Go to bed instead and do it next morning!

Comment: Yeah, it happens XD